I want to colorize the points of a Shapviz dependence output acording to the variable
I have been trying to change the colors of the points on each variable, but even though i've tried using scale_x_discrete, by and changing the colors, or using scale_color_manual(), nothing works for me.
When I try to use a list of colors on the sv_dependence function (color =""), i get the error:
"Error in ggplot2::geom_jitter(): ! Problem while setting up geom aesthetics. ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer. Caused by error in check_aesthetics(): ! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1000). ✖ Fix the following mappings: colour."

I spent several hours trying to change it, but i am not able.
Someone to help me please?

I am using the following libraries and my code currently is as follow, but it gets me just one color for the whole graphic...
library(kernelshap)
library(shapviz)
library(ggplot2)

#COS
names_cos=c('ART','AGRI','PAST','HDW','EUC','RES','SHL')
#dep_cos<-

cos_dep<-sv_dependence(sv, v = "cos",color_var=NULL,color="gray30")

cos_dep+
scale_x_discrete(labels = names_cos, limits = factor(1:7))+
  labs(y = "SHAP value",
    x = "LCU")+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(tag = "(b)") +
  theme(plot.tag = element_text(),
  plot.tag.position = c(0.95, 0.1))

dep_cos$layers <- c(
  list(geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "black")),
  dep_cos$layers
)
dep_cos

I was expecting to get one different color per X Class (one for ART, one for AGRI,...,etc)

Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your input data best shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset. From my understanding of the docs you can set the variable to color by using the color_var argument which you have set to NULL.

Coloring in SHAP dependence plots is to visualize interaction effects. The only variable where it does not make sense to study interactions with is the variable on the x axis. This is the reason why sv_dependence() suppresses v as the color_var. Maybe, in your situation, it feels bad. But it allows quite neatly the use of multiple color variables or multiple x variables.
Since sv_dependence() in its basic form is simply a scatter plot, you can easily make your own special version.
library(xgboost)
library(shapviz)
library(ggplot2)

X_pred <- data.matrix(iris[, -1])
dtrain <- xgboost::xgb.DMatrix(X_pred, label = iris[, 1])
fit <- xgboost::xgb.train(data = dtrain, nrounds = 10)

shap_obj <- shapviz(fit, X_pred = X_pred, X = iris)


df <- data.frame(Species = shap_obj$X$Species, SHAP_value = shap_obj$S[, "Species"])
ggplot(df, aes(Species, SHAP_value, color = Species)) +
  geom_jitter()


